# Change InternationalizationCheck from JSTL '<fmt:message key>' format?

Tags: internationalization, sonarqube

In the SonarQube Web Plugin, the InternationalizationCheck rule searches for internationalization in the form of `<fmt:message key=...>`. Is there any way to change this? All my internationalization is in the format `<f: message key=...>`. I assume this was alterable in the 'attributes' section, but I haven't figured out what exactly that section is for, or what to put there.

For example, currently the rule searches for any internationalization in the form of

```
<fmt:message key="login.label.username" />
```

As described in the rule's noncompliant/compliant code example. However, in my application, internationalization takes the form of

```
<f:message key="login.label.username" />
```

Which is incorrectly labelled as an error by the rule. Nothing in the InternationalizationCheck's [source code](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-web/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/web/checks/coding/InternationalizationCheck.java) shows how it explicitly looks for the that format, so I need to find a way to make it accept my format as an acceptable line of code instead of giving it a false positive.

Is there any way to specify for the InternationalizationCheck to look for a different format of Internationalization, other than the JSTL taglib prefix of 'fmt'?

Comment: We're struggling a little bit to understand the question. Could you provide an example ? Thanks

Comment: @Freddy-SonarSourceTeam I added clarification. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: I think there is little misunderstanding here because the rule 'InternationalizationCheck' (see http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=web|q=InternationalizationCheck) is not looking for occurrences of <fmt:message .../> tags but only of plain text directly injected into the HTML document. Example: <div>My Section</div> instead of <div><f:message key="mySection"/></div>. Could you provide me the HTML piece of code on which you're getting an unexpected issue ? Thanks

Comment: @Freddy-SonarSourceTeam Oh I see. It looks like none of the errors that are coming up have zero non-externalized text, but just has text that won't be externalized, like '*' or 'CAD'. Is there any way to add exceptions to the rule to omit these plain text occurrences?

Comment: @Freddy-SonarSourceTeam from what I can see, there isn't any way to have 'excepted' plain text from the rule. If there indeed isn't, is there somewhere I can find the process of importing the source code for that rule and changing it to add one?

Comment: Do you agree that a way to fix this limitation would be to make it possible to inject a regular expression as a parameter of this rule to define an exclusion pattern ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that would be a helpful addition.

Comment: Perfect, ticket created https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARWEB-41 and feel free to contribute if you want/can: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-web